# Is there a way to add Bluetooth functionality to an ErgoDox EZ keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

It would be nice to have some sort of mini-USB accessory that could bluetooth-enable an ErgodoxEZ keyboard.

I found some related discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ergodox/comments/8kugs5/is_it_possible_to_add_bluetooth_functionality_to/, but that thread has been archived, and there's not yet a clear solution yet, so I'm moving the discussion here.  The stackexchange format is better for such discussions anyway.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. However, recommendations for specific products are off-limits on this site. Questions about the use of commercial products are also off-limits.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that *"Is it possible ...?"* is a yes/no question. In this case, the answer is "Yes". If you're asking us to design it for you, that would be too broad. You would need to specify something about the level of performance you expect as well as what constraints you have on the implementation. What is your specific question? Furthermore, this is not a "discussion" site, it's a question-answer site.

Answer (score 4):

I tried out the bluetooth adapter mentioned at the end of the above reddit post (http://handheldsci.com/kb).  The adapter *somewhat* works with an Ergodox, but is inconsistent.

It seems to work fine for any of the "regular" keys (keys on the first layer of the ergodox that are single-function).  However, if you have a a key mapped to `ctrl+z`, `ctrl+s`, `cmd+z`, etc., that key will *sometimes* work, but is flakey & inconsistent.  Also, any keys on other-than the first layer are somewhat flakey in the same way.

It does appear that that adapter would work fine with a "regular" keyboard, or anyone who is only using an Ergodox for ergonomics reasons (has a fairly-standard, single-layer configuration).

I hope that help anyone else thinking of trying that adapter out.